# Can`t debug iphone apps with on xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I can`t debug apps on my test device.
Error says,

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

I created the distribution provisioning file for App store.
Then on xcode, changed the build configuration to Release.

But above error shows.

When I debug with Debug mode, it works.

Could someone help me with this problem?

Comment: You mention that when you debug in debug it works, does it work on the device or only the emulator?

Comment: In debug, it works on both.
In release, it works on emulator, but don`t work on device.

Comment: To debug apps you need a DEVELOPMENT provisioning profile. DISTRIBUTION profiles/certificates will let you install a build on the device, but not launch from Xcode/attach the debugger.

Comment: You can´t launch more than 1 time your app with Distribution Profile with usb connected to Device. You should create a Development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type provisioning profile that you need to 'directly' run on your device is called 'Ad hoc'.

Not sure it still is the only way today but before you had to put the .ipa in your itunes and synchronise to install the application.

Nowadays, I find it is easier in the long run just to upload the 'appstore' builds to itunes connect build and enable testflight instead of the 'ad hoc' way